# Are Apex interfaces and abstract classes case-sensitive?

Tags: apex, interface, inheritance

My understanding from the docs is that apex class and method names are case-insensitive.

I've run across an edge-case with interfaces and abstract classes which appears to be undocumented behavior where it is case-sensitive. The following 3 stub classes reproduce the issue which I believe is a compiler bug.

Base Interface

```
public interface overrideInterface {
    void camelCase();
}
```

Abstract Class

```
public abstract class SL_override implements overrideInterface{
    public virtual void camelCase() {
        system.debug('should never run.');
    }
}
```

Class to Run

```
public class SL_newOverride extends SL_Override {
    //capital A
    public override void camelCAse(){
        system.debug('will never run.');
    }
}
```

Anonymous Apex

```
SL_newOverride foo = new SL_newOverride();
foo.camelCase();
```

If you run this anonymous apex it appears to never enter the methods and errors out:

```
Error on line -1, column -1: System.LimitException: Maximum stack depth reached: 1001
External entry point
External entry point
External entry point
External entry point
External entry point
External entry point
External entry point
External entry point
...
```

Comment: You haven't opened a case for this by chance, have you?

Comment: @ca_peterson, not yet. Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious before going through the exercise.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this myself - my attempt debugs the expected value from the concrete implementation class - not anything like a infinite recursion issue. Are you sure there's not more to this issue?

Comment: @GregGrinberg can you capture the Apex debug log when the problem occurs. Set the Apex Code log level to FINE, FINER, or FINEST. Can you also check the API versions on all three classes and that the ApexClass Id's are lining up with the Id's showing in the log.

Comment: @ca_peterson - I spun up a new dev org just to make sure and I can still reproduce this. 

All classes are api 43. 

This is the debug log. Appears to be calling the camelcase method over and over.
https://gist.github.com/grigri9/41da12424d5a9614cd99cc0ca767ed24

Comment: If either of you are interested I can just shoot you the dev org credentials over SE chat as it's a brand new org with nothing else in there.

Comment: @GregGrinberg can you share the orgId instead? As a rule I don't like to touch customer credentials.

Comment: @ca_peterson 00D300000006fTZ - It's a partner developer org.

Comment: @ca_peterson, any results?

Comment: BTW it's only reproducible if you have the extension `SL_newOverride` as a top-level class. I tried extending a top-level by a nested, extend nested by nested and nested by top-level. And it only behaves that way when you extending whatever by a top-level class

Answer (score 2):

This is an unique case. I tried your code and got the same stack depth error. But I play around with the method name and what I observed that not all the combinations of Upper-case and Lower-case letters in the method name are behaving in the same way. For example, I changed the **Interface class** method name as follows

```
    public interface overrideInterface {
    void camelcaSE();
    void METHOD2();
}
```

Then I change the Abstract Class method name as follows

```
public abstract class SL_override implements overrideInterface{

     public virtual void camelCase() {
        system.debug('should never run.');
    }
      public virtual void Method2() {
        system.debug('Abstract class Method2() display- Interface method name - METHOD2()');
    }
}
```

Then I changed the method name in the child class as follows

```
public class SL_newOverride extends SL_Override {

    public override void camelcASE(){
        super.camelcase();
        system.debug('will never run.');
    }

    public override void metHod2(){
        super.method2();
        system.debug('method2 display.');
    }
}
```

Then I invoke and execute the child class through anonymous apex as follows

```
SL_newOverride foo = new SL_newOverride();
foo.camelCasE();
```

And it works fine. The only situation the case-sensitivity is becoming the issue is **camelCAse()**. Otherwise, I don't think the **Apex naming convention is case-sensitive**. The proof is with the second method name **Method2** which I declared in the **interface class and overridden in the abstract and child classes**.

```
SL_newOverride foo = new SL_newOverride();
foo.camelCasE();
foo.Method2();
```

**So we can't conclude that Salesforce Apex class methods are case sensitive**.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [Get Started with Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro) trailhead article. It includes following line.

> In addition, Apex is a case-insensitive language.

Here is a [similar question to this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251016/is-apex-sometimes-case-sensitive) and it has some good answers. I think it is better to go through them as well. These answers explains where is case-sensitivity applying and not.