# Is Apex Sometimes Case Sensitive?

Tags: apex, string, contains

I have a string set of field names populated as below:

```
Set<String> setAllCustomSettingFields = new Set<String>();

Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for(String objectName : gd.keySet()){
    Schema.SObjectType result = gd.get(objectName);
    if(result.getDescribe().isCustomSetting()){
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = result.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        for(String fieldString : objectFields.keySet()) {
            setAllCustomSettingFields.add(fieldString);
        }
    }
}
```

All the strings in the set turn out to be all lowercase.  It contains, for example, '**api_url__c**.'

However, `setAllCustomSettingFields.contains('API_URL__c')` was false, whereas `setAllCustomSettingFields.contains('api_url__c')` is true.

I have never seen that before, always thought all Apex is case insensitive, and the documentation on contains() doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. **Collection membership is case sensitive**.

This applies to [Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm):

> If the set contains String elements, the elements are case-sensitive. Two set elements that differ only by case are considered distinct.

and to [Maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_methods_system_map):

> Map keys of type String are case-sensitive. Two keys that differ only by the case are considered unique and have corresponding distinct Map entries. Subsequently, the Map methods, including put, get, containsKey, and remove treat these keys as distinct.

Comment: +1 Except for "magic" maps, like the one returned from getGlobalDescribe.

Comment: yeah, the map is magic but the keyset from the map is not (ex. , `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap().keyset().contains('LastName')` is false. The keyset contains all lowercase instead of correct API field name casing.

Comment: @sfdcfox - can you talk more about magic maps?

Answer (score 7):

Map keys and contains checks (and the same with `Set` or `List`) are always case sensitive, with the one exception of describes such as `fields.getMap()` or `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`. However, as soon as you pull the keyset and put it somewhere else, you lose this magical property.

Answer (score 6):

From SF docs on [Mapss](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm):

> Map keys of type String are case-sensitive. Two keys that differ only
>   by the case are considered unique and have corresponding distinct Map
>   entries. Subsequently, the Map methods, including put, get,
>   containsKey, and remove treat these keys as distinct.

From SF DOcs on [Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm)

> If the set contains String elements, the elements are case-sensitive.
>   Two set elements that differ only by case are considered distinct.

Maps and Set uses Hash Collision and hence they treat keys as the case sensitive.

The only exception is `Set<Id>` and `Map<Id,Object>`

```
Set<Id> setId = new Set<Id>{'0060D0000038F05'};

System.debug(setId.contains('0060D0000038F05QAE')); //Prints true
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not Apex case sensitivity but a `String` case sensitivity.

You are comparing `String` values in the `Set` and thus it will always evaluate based on its equality which is case sensitive. So if your `Set` contains `api_url__c`, that's not same as `API_URL__C`.

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm):

> - Uniqueness of set elements of user-defined types is determined by the equals and hashCode methods, which you provide in your classes. Uniqueness of all other non-primitive types is determined by comparing the objects’ fields.
> - If the set contains **String** elements, the elements are **case-sensitive**. Two set elements that differ only by case are considered distinct.

Comment: Can you provide a couple of practical examples where apex is not case sensitive, to contrast with this? I'm sure I know some, but am drawing a blank

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana What I mean here by Apex not being case sensitive is you can write `String var = 'myname'` which is same as `string VAR = 'myname'`. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the map/set answers and not specifically Apex but relevant in Apex use of SOQL:

[Platform Encryption deterministic encryption](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/218/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_platform_encryption_implementation_guide.pdf)

> When you use case-sensitive deterministic encryption, case matters. In
>   reports, list views, and SOQL queries on encrypted fields, the results
>   are case-sensitive. Therefore, a SOQL query against the Contact
>   object, where LastName = 'Jones’, returns only Jones, not jones nor
>   JONES. Similarly, when the case-sensitive deterministic scheme tests
>   for unicity (uniqueness), each version of “Jones” is unique.
>
> Case-Insensitive Deterministic Encryption (Beta as of V45) and Custom Field
>   Allocations To allow case-insensitive queries, Salesforce stores a
>   lowercase duplicate of your data as a custom field in the database.
>   While these duplicates are necessary to enable case-insensitive
>   queries, they count against your total custom field count.